# How to easily change the contents of str(function) in python

Tags: python, string, function, class

Printing a python function directly always gives you an ugly and lengthy string.

```
def myfunc_addition(a,b):
    return a + b

print(myfunc_addition(1, 2)) # 3
print(str(myfunc_addition)) # <function myfunc_addition at 0x00000215FC2BC8C8>
```

I want to change this but I have no idea how to achieve it. I googled with "string expression of a function python" and "python how to change str(function)" but they didn't help me much.

All I could come up with was the code below. This is not great since you have to initialize an object.

```
class Myfunc:
    def __call__(self, a,b) -> int:
        return a + b
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return '+'

m = Myfunc()
print(m(1,2)) # 3
print(str(m)) # +
```

How should I easily change the contents of str(function)?

Comment: `myfunc_addition.__str__ = lambda: "Your message here"`

Comment: @JohnGordon `myfunc_addition` gave `<function __main__.myfunc_addition(a, b)>`. It doesn't seem like __str__() can be overwritten.

Comment: @JohnGordon: You can't override magic methods on an instance like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling it as `str(function)` isn't strictly required, you could add a [docstring](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/) to the function and then print that:

```
def myfunc_addition(a, b):
  """+"""
  return a+b

print(myfunc_addition.__doc__)
+
```

This has the benefit that Python already supports docstrings in the function definition.